# handle multiple timers with the class timer

Tags: flutter, dart

I've trying to do a multiple timer in flutter, when one ends, another one should start, for some reason, when the first timer ends, the next one doesn't begin. Here is the code

```
  Timer timer;
    
  //Create the sets
  void startSets(){
    startTimer(10,0); //10 seconds, 0 minutes
      for(int i=0; i<sets;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<exercises;j++){
          startTimer(15,0); //15 seconds, 0 minutes
        }
        startTimer(12,0); //12 seconds, 0 minutes
      }
  }

  void stopTimer(){ 
    timer.cancel();
  }

  void startTimer(int seconds, int minutes){ 
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        if(seconds>0){
          seconds--;
        }else if(seconds==0 && minutes>0){
          minutes--;
          seconds = 59;
        }else{
          timer.cancel();
        }
        minText=minToString(minutes);
        secText=secToString(seconds);
      });
    });
  }
```

minText and secText are global variables which I use for a Text Widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't match your description.  You say you want one `Timer` to start when another one ends, but `startSets` start all its `Timer`s at the same time without any waiting.  If you actually want only one `Timer` in-flight at a time, you will need to create a queue that you process when each `Timer` completes.

One way to do it would be something like (this is untested code):

```dart
var timerQueue = Queue<Duration>();
Timer currentTimer;
  
//Create the sets
void startSets() {
  timerQueue.add(Duration(seconds: 10));
  for (var i = 0; i < sets; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < exercises; j++) {
      timerQueue.add(Duration(seconds: 15));
    }
    timerQueue.add(Duration(seconds: 12));
  }

  startNextTimer();
}

void stopTimer() { 
  currentTimer?.cancel();
  currentTimer = null;
}

void startNextTimer() {
  if (timerQueue.isEmpty) {
    return;
  }

  var duration = timerQueue.removeFirst();
  var seconds = duration.inSeconds % 60;
  var minutes = duration.inMinutes;

  assert(currentTimer == null);
  currentTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
    setState(() {
      if (seconds > 0){
        seconds--;
      } else if (seconds == 0 && minutes > 0) {
        minutes--;
        seconds = 59;
      } else {
        currentTimer.cancel();
        currentTimer = null;
      }
      minText = minToString(minutes);
      secText = secToString(seconds);

      if (currentTimer == null) {
        startNextTimer();
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

declare timer variable inside startTimer method like this

```
  void startTimer(int seconds, int minutes){ 
  Timer timer;
  ...
  }
```

so that for every time startTimer is called it will be declared